# Firebase Firestore - Best way to call a bunch of where gets?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of user emails that I want to then pull from firebase each of the corresponding user documents from a collection where one of the email matches. I don't want to pull the whole collection as it would be expensive. What is the easiest way to do this? I tried for looping over the array with individual gets to firebase but ran into promise issues as I want to do something in Javascript with them right after.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

based on what i understood from your question i can only think of using await Promise.all() -  you can look into this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

as an example you could pass an array of promises to await Promise.all() so you could do

```
const res = await Promise.all(
array.map( x => db.collection('users')
.where('email' , '==', x.email).limit(1).get());
```

mind you that in this example you would still have to process the result as they will return a snapshot not a document ...

**Update:**

Hey there, i just noticed that you can use in operator `in` firebase query, which will return the values matching in a given array.

i'm not sure but maybe using it might be suitable in your use-case you can check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)